# How to get "this" type in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

```
class A {
    method : this = () => this;
}
```

What I want is for *this*, used as the return type, to represent the current class, i.e a subclass a of A. So, method only returns the values of the same type as the class (not *only* the base class, A).

---

I think I've got something similar with this:

```
class A {
    method : <T extends A> () => T = () => this;
}
```

But this seems superfluous. I've duplicated `A`. Surely there's a better way to do this?..

Comment: Why would `this` return _a subclass of A_; by definition, `this` represents the execution context - in the case of the code above, that is A. In the second example, the execution context is still A, so returning `this` will return A. Please consider reading this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: @RandyCasburn using `this` was merely an example, to easily illustrate what I'm trying to do. Of course `this` wouldn't represent a class.

Comment: As I mentioned to artem below, I thought you were confusing the RunTime characteristics of JavaScript with the static type checking characteristics of TypeScript. But I realize I must have misinterpreted your question.

Comment: @RandyCasburn I'd actually just been stupid. `this` works as a type, just as I was wanting it to. But, I was setting `methods` type to `this`, not *a function that __returns__* `this`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost got it, the type of `method` property should be declared as `() => this`, not just `this`. The compiler understands that when used as a type, `this` is [polymorphic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#polymorphic-this-types)

```
class A {
    method : () => this = () => this;
}

class B extends A {

}

const b = new B();

const bb = b.method(); // inferred as const bb: B;
```

Comment: Because the execution context is now B. Polymorphic as described in the TypeScript docs, yes, but plain old JavaScript in the way it works.

Comment: Yes but the question was about how to properly describe its type in TypeScript. There's no `method` defined for `class B`, so `method` in `A` needs some special way to declare its type.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But the OP goes on to confuse the static type checking nature of TypeScript with the Run Time execution of JavaScript (_So, method only returns the values_). But I realize now I've probably misinterpreted the intent.